# ORA-00904: Invalid Identifier when selecting from view

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am attempting to view a view with:

```
select * from DISCOUNT_AMOUNTS;
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00904: "SALE_GIFT_VOUCHER_AMOUNT_AMOUN": invalid identifier
```

I then check the view to see what is there in view.

```
DESC DISCOUNT_AMOUNTS;
 Name                                                                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------------------------------
 LINE_ITEM_AUDIT_ID                                                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(18)
 CREATED_DATE                                                                              NOT NULL DATE
 SALE_AMOUNT_AMOUNT                                                                                 NUMBER
 SALE_PROMPT_PAY_AMOUNT_AMOUNT                                                                      NUMBER
 SALE_QUANTITY_AMOUNT_AMOUNT                                                                        NUMBER
 SALE_RETAILER_AMOUNT_AMOUNT                                                                        NUMBER
 SALE_MANUFACTURE_AMOUNT_AMOUNT                                                                     NUMBER
 SALE_REBATE_AMOUNT_AMOUNT                                                                          NUMBER
 SALE_TRADE_IN_AMOUNT_AMOUNT                                                                        NUMBER
 SALE_REWARD_RETL_PROM_AMOUNT_A                                                                     NUMBER
 SALE_REWARD_MANU_PROM_AMOUNT_A                                                                     NUMBER
 SALE_REWARD_CC_AMOUNT_AMOUNT                                                                       NUMBER
 SALE_GIFT_VOUCHER_AMOUNT_AMOUN                                                                     NUMBER
```

I then check it directly with single quotes of

```
select 'SALE_GIFT_VOUCHER_AMOUNT_AMOUN' from DISCOUNT_AMOUNTS;
```

which returns successfully.

I then attempt:

```
SQL> alter view DISCOUNT_AMOUNTS compile;
View altered.
```

Reattempt

```
select * from DISCOUNT_AMOUNTS;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "SALE_GIFT_VOUCHER_AMOUNT_AMOUN": invalid identifier
```

This is not making sense to me.  I can compile, it exists in view, but it won't select in wild character search.  What else can I try?  It is 30 characters as well and running command as user who created the view.

This is the create or replace view statement.  Am on 12.1, which is 30 characters I believe. 12.2 is 128 for identifiers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DISCOUNT_AMOUNTS
AS
SELECT
LINE_ITEM_AUDIT_ID,
CREATED_DATE,
SALE_AMOUNT_AMOUNT,
SALE_PROMPT_PAY_AMOUNT_AMOUNT,
SALE_QUANTITY_AMOUNT_AMOUNT,
SALE_RETAILER_AMOUNT_AMOUNT,
SALE_MANUFACTURE_AMOUNT_AMOUNT,
SALE_REBATE_AMOUNT_AMOUNT,
SALE_TRADE_IN_AMOUNT_AMOUNT,
SALE_REWARD_RETL_PROM_AMOUNT_A,
SALE_REWARD_MANU_PROM_AMOUNT_A,
SALE_REWARD_CC_AMOUNT_AMOUNT,
SALE_GIFT_VOUCHER_AMOUNT_AMOUN
FROM
(SELECT LINE_ITEM_AUDIT_ID,
DISCOUNT_TYPE_ID,
DISCOUNT_AMOUNT,
CREATED_DATE
FROM LINE_DISCOUNT_AUDIT
) PIVOT ( SUM(DISCOUNT_AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FOR (DISCOUNT_TYPE_ID) IN ( 
1 AS SALE_AMOUNT, 
2 AS SALE_PROMPT_PAY_AMOUNT, 
3 AS SALE_QUANTITY_AMOUNT, 
4 AS SALE_RETAILER_AMOUNT, 
5 AS SALE_MANUFACTURE_AMOUNT, 
6 AS SALE_REBATE_AMOUNT, 
7 AS SALE_TRADE_IN_AMOUNT, 
8 AS SALE_REWARD_RETL_PROM_AMOUNT, 
9 AS SALE_REWARD_MANU_PROM_AMOUNT, 
10 AS SALE_REWARD_CC_AMOUNT, 
11 AS SALE_GIFT_VOUCHER_AMOUNT));
```

Comment: Are there any column level permissions on the base table (or view)?

Comment: Show us the view definition. Did you enclose the table alias/name in quotes when you created the view, and if so was it lower/mixed case?

Comment: What version of database server and client are you using?  
Column names were limited to 30 characters until very recently so it might be that an older /client/ might have problems with them.

Comment: This works perfectly: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5aa0556f8a68e9193343194c2df9832

Comment: Is there another object called `LINE_DISCOUNT_AUDIT` in the database? There may be a synonym in play here. Recreate the view and qualify `LINE_DISCOUNT_AUDIT` with the schema name (eg: `YOURUSER. LINE_DISCOUNT_AUDIT`) and see if it fixes things

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ  I believe that is the issue.  The schema owner was different for that object than the others.  Thanks!

Comment: NB `select 'SALE_GIFT_VOUCHER_AMOUNT_AMOUN' from DISCOUNT_AMOUNTS;` is selecting a string constant, one for each row, from your view. It's not returning a particular column from your view. Single quotes define strings in SQL, double quotes can be used to force a particular case on the column identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Your test case works perfectly as-is: [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5aa0556f8a68e9193343194c2df9832)

Is there another object called `LINE_DISCOUNT_AUDIT` in the database? There may be a synonym in play here. Recreate the view and qualify `LINE_DISCOUNT_AUDIT` with the schema name (eg: `YOURUSER. LINE_DISCOUNT_AUDIT`).